# Implementing efficient "Customers who viewed this, also bought that" recommendation algorithm

Tags: python, recommender-system, similarity, python-3.x

I'm not sure how to formulate this but I'll have a go. This code should be completely reproducible given the data below. I hope I've been clear in my question.

I'm trying to implement a recommendation algorithm for recommendations of the type "Customers who viewed item A, also bought Item B", see this [link](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/target/assets/log-likelihood-ratios-recommendation-algorithms.pdf?lang=en) for reference if needed. So if some customer views item A, we recommend B to him/her. To do this I have the following customer/item interaction data during a 7 day period:

```
        CustomerID  OptionID        Viewed         Bought
-----------------------------------------------------
0       4270878350  1023877-01      1              0
1       2670959473  1023877-01      1              0
2       2036378566  1023877-01      1              0
3       790973671   1023914-01      1              0
4       1136507496  1023914-01      1              1
...     ...         ...             ...            ...
628668  482706165   7019194-02      1              0
628669  432961878   7019194-02      1              0
628670  1934346436  7019194-02      1              1
628671  2034276267  7019194-02      1              0
628672  445273170   7019194-02      1              0
```

Where OptionID is the ID for an item. Note that `Viewed = 1` in all entries. The next step is to, for each pair, construct a contingency matrix of the form

```
       B        ~B
 A     k1      n1-k1
~A     k2      n2-k2
```

where, ∼B means “did not purchase B” etc. So here, we have n1 people who viewed A, of
whom k1 also purchased B, while n2 people did not view A, of whom k2 purchased B. I have a function that calculates n1,k1,n2,k2 in the contingency table given the data frame, A and B, called . From this table I need to do some calculations, I have three functions called `get_n1_k1(df,A,B)`, `get_n2_k2(df,A,B)` and `get_llr(n1,k1,n2,k2)`. The last function just calculates a log-likelihood ratio that is used as similarity score between the items A and B. All these functions do the calculations fast and is a non-factor in the computational speed. Here are these functions:

```
import numpy as np

def get_n1_k1(df, A, B):

    #Filter the DataFrame for all rows where the OptionID is equal to "A" and the Viewed column is equal to 1.
    viewed_A = df[(df["OptionID"] == A) & (df["Viewed"] == 1)]

    #From the filtered DataFrame, extract a list of unique CustomerIDs who viewed "A"
    customers_viewed_A = viewed_A["CustomerID"].unique()
    n1 = len(customers_viewed_A)

    #Filter the DataFrame for all rows where the OptionID is equal to "B" and the Bought column is equal to 1.
    bought_B = df[(df["OptionID"] == B) & (df["Bought"] == 1)]

    #From the filtered DataFrame, extract a list of unique CustomerIDs who bought "B"
    customers_bought_B = bought_B["CustomerID"].unique()

    #Calculate the intersection of "customers_viewed_A" and "customers_bought_B"
    customers_viewed_A_and_bought_B = set(customers_viewed_A).intersection(set(customers_bought_B))

    #The length of "customers_viewed_A_and_bought_B" is the number of customers who viewed "A" and also bought "B"
    k1 = len(customers_viewed_A_and_bought_B)
    
    return n1,k1

def get_n2_k2(df, A, B):
    
    #Filter the DataFrame for all rows where the OptionID is NOT equal to "A"
    not_viewed_A = df[(df["OptionID"] != A)]

    #From the filtered DataFrame, extract a list of unique CustomerIDs who did not view "A"
    customers_not_viewed_A = not_viewed_A["CustomerID"].unique()

    #Filter the DataFrame for all rows where the OptionID is equal to "B" and the Bought column is equal to 1.
    bought_B = df[(df["OptionID"] == B) & (df["Bought"] == 1)]

    #From the filtered DataFrame, extract a list of unique CustomerIDs who bought "B"
    customers_bought_B = bought_B["CustomerID"].unique()

    #Calculate the intersection of "customers_not_viewed_A" and "customers_bought_B"
    customers_not_viewed_A_and_bought_B = set(customers_not_viewed_A).intersection(set(customers_bought_B))

    #Calculate the number of customers who did not view "A"
    n2 = len(customers_not_viewed_A)

    #Calculate the number of customers who did not view "A" but bought "B"
    k2 = len(customers_not_viewed_A_and_bought_B)
    
    return n2,k2

def get_llr(n1,k1,n2,k2):
    
    #create alpha, beta and epsilon to avoide NaN values  and division by zero
    if n1 == 0 or n2 == 0:
        alpha = 2
    else:
        alpha = 0
    
    if n1 == 0 and n2 == 0:
        beta = 1
    else:
        beta = 0
    
    if k1 == 0 or k2 == 0:
        epsilon = 1e-3
    else:
        epsilon = 0
    
    #calculate the maximum likelihood estimations for p0, p1 and p2
    p0 = (k1 + k2 + epsilon) / (n1 + n2 + beta)
    p1 = (k1 + epsilon) / (n1 + alpha)
    p2 = (k2 + epsilon) / (n2 + alpha)
    
    #calculate the log-likelihood ratio for A,B
    llr_1 = k1*np.log(p1) + (n1 - k1)*np.log(1 - p1)
    llr_2 = k2*np.log(p2) + (n2 - k2)*np.log(1 - p2)
    llr_3 = k1*np.log(p0) + (n1 - k1)*np.log(1 - p0)
    llr_4 = k2*np.log(p0) + (n2 - k2)*np.log(1 - p0)

    llr = llr_1 + llr_2 - llr_3 - llr_4
    
    return llr
```

So far so good. The functions above do what I want them to do and I get the correct answer.

### Now to the problem.

I need to calculate the `llr` for all pairs of A and B. To do this I'm using the following code:

```
from itertools import combinations

similarity_scores = {}

data = 'The data above...'

for A,B in combinations(data['OptionID'].unique(), 2):

    n1,k1 = get_n1_k1(data, A, B)
    n2,k2 = get_n2_k2(data, A, B)
    llr = get_llr(n1,k1,n2,k2)
    
    similarity_scores[(A, B)] = llr
    similarity_scores[(B, A)] = llr
```

This takes several days to complete even for small data sets. I don't know how to solve this issue. Are there other ways of doing computations like these? I have no idea how to implement vectorization technique here since I need to calculate the contingency table for each pair of items. Any ideas, tips or tricks are very welcomed.